# Filtering messages with/without answers

Tags: support, search

Tags can now be filtered.  For example, 
hasaccepted:no is syntax for do not
show questions with accepted answers.

Why doesn't hasanswer:no remove
all questions with answers?
Why doesn't onhold:no remove all
questions that are on hold?
Is the syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is explained on the [search page](https://math.stackexchange.com/search) under "Advanced Search Tips".

To filter out questions with answers, use `answers:0`

To filter out closed questions, use `closed:0` or `closed:no`.

The "on hold" status is mostly a euphemism for "closed" and the search engine does not care about the distinction.

Comment: If I use closed:0 and a question of mine gets closed, how would I know that?

Comment: How do I remove both answered questions and has accepted answer simultaneously?  Can I also removed closed questions in addition?

Comment: All search parameters can be used in combination. But if a question has no answers, it seems safe to conclude it has no accepted answer.